# Error with hibernate search in ejbModule

Tags: hibernate, ejb-3.1, hibernate-search, full-text-indexing, jboss-eap-7

For my final project, I plan to implement hibernate search in an ejb module.
Since the call by a remote client to index my database, I have the exeption below:

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.SearchFactoryReference]

Please find below my codes :

**1. my ejb session:**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.search.FullTextSession;
import org.hibernate.search.Search;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class HibernateIndexer
 */
@Stateless(name="HIND")
@LocalBean
public class HibernateIndexer implements HibernateIndexerRemote, HibernateIndexerLocal {

    protected Configuration config;
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected Session session;
    protected FullTextSession ftx;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public HibernateIndexer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        config=new Configuration();
        sessionFactory= config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        ftx=Search.getFullTextSession(session);     
    }

    public void indexer(){       

    try {
        ftx.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     session.close();
    }

}
```

**2. My ejb entities**

**2.1 TgPersonnePer.java**

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.DocumentId;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.IndexedEmbedded;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;

@Indexed
public class TgPersonnePer implements java.io.Serializable {

    @DocumentId
    private String perId;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private TgPersonneMoralePer tgPersonneMoralePer;

    public TgPersonnePer() {
    }

    public TgPersonnePer(String perId) {
        this.perId = perId;
    }
// setter and getter
...................
}
```

**2.2  TgPersonneMoralePer.java**

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;

public class TgPersonneMoralePer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String perId;
    private TgPersonnePer tgPersonnePer;
    @Field
    private String perDenoSociale;
    @Field
    private String perSigle;

    public TgPersonneMoralePer() {
    }

    public TgPersonneMoralePer(TgPersonnePer tgPersonnePer) {
        this.tgPersonnePer = tgPersonnePer;
    }

    // Setter and getter
     .................
}
```

**3. My hibernate config file : hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>      
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">exam</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">azerty</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>

                <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!--  Hibernate research configuration-->

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">D:\Lucene\indexes</property>


        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update">org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener</property>

        <mapping resource="org/module/entities/TgPersonneMoralePer.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="org/module/entities/TgPersonnePer.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**4. My jboss deployment structure : jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" slot="main"/>
      <module name="javax.transaction.api" slot="main"/>
      <module name="org.javassist"/>

      <!-- Module de hibernate Search -->
      <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" slot="main"/>
      <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine" slot="main"/>
      <module name="org.apache.lucene" slot="main"/>
      <module name="org.apache.lucene.internal" slot="main"/>

    </dependencies>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.javassist" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the services from the Hibernate Search ORM module.

So something like the following would be in order:

```
<module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" services="export" slot="main"/>
```

Adding this module should be enough to get Hibernate Search running, you shouldn't need to add the other modules (engine and lucene).

Comment: Alternatively, if you use the latest WilFly 10.1 you don't need any `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` : the right dependencies will be setup automatically. You only need to override that if you want to use a different version of any Hibernate library than the ones included in WildFly.